# Radio button validation with error handling in c# WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hi I have 3 radio button with 10, 20, 30 value in it and 4th radio button is other with textbox next to it for user to enter any other number value in it.
I would like to show message when user doesn't select any radio button or if they enter wrong data other than number in other radio button text box.
here is my code

Comment: And the question is.. ? what is wrong with this code? are you getting any error?

Comment: yes I'm asking what is wrong with code and I'm not getting any error.
I'm New at this

Comment: I'm getting error on tryparse at the bottom

Comment: please be more clear. What is the error you are getting, what `**` before `else if ` denotes and what is the difficulty you are facing

Comment: Your code does nothing. It modifies the local variable `years` and returns.

Comment: I was trying to make bold font for error when in was asking this question on stockoverflow. that's ** from

Comment: what I want to do is check if user have selected any radio button and if the user have selected radio button with "Other" option. check the input from user if it's integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bit unclear, I assume(from comments), you want to show a message when user inputs *non*  double value in the textbox, Use`MessageBox.Show` to show the message.

Comment: for some reason text box next to radiobutton doesn't work when you put in right input
It doesn't do anything and doesn't return any error

Comment: @Sam2704 I'm not sure why you _unmarked_  marked answer, seems what you are asking now is an extension to the question. I suggest post new question with changed requirement, it might confuse SO users reaching this post with similar issue, hope you understand :-).

Comment: There are lots of experts, but definitely I toss my coin too ;-)

Comment: I have posted question can you at least check where my error is?

Comment: Can you post the link, I don't yet see the question in stack.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672373/c-sharp-wpf-radio-button-with-textbox-doesnt-work