# C# WPF radio button with textbox doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

When you type in wrong data it shows right errors but when you enter right information it doesn't do anything in radio button textbox. It doesn't return any error either.

I need radio button to get the correct year from user and pass it to Years variable.

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: What do you want to do when you input correct `double` value? Please post your complete code and tell what you need.

Comment: When user enters right input for example it's asking for number of years for loan. so it needs to do tryparse and load the value in years variable.

Comment: Code is already doing this, I suggest move `return false` inside if statement.

Comment: Once i moved "return false" inside if statement. error showed up on "get".  After Private bool IsValidated

Comment: I have added whole code again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you have to return `false` for wrong year input.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it is fixed :-)